# How to exit program using autohotkey?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, autohotkey

I am using autohotkey to do some automate process.

I need help with closing chrome.exe

**I tried**

```
        Process, Close,  chrome.exe
;    or
        Run taskkill /im chrome.exe
```

but it give me chrome crashed error when I start it again.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `WinClose` to send a close message to the window, rather than killing the process:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
WinClose Google Chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

[mihai's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14106157/45375) works well if a *single* Chrome window (typically containing multiple *tabs*) is open.

However, **more work is needed if you want to close *all* open Chrome windows**:

```
; Get all hWnds (window IDs) created by chrome.exe processes.
WinGet hWnds, List, ahk_exe chrome.exe

; Loop over all hWnds and close them.
Loop, %hWnds%
{
  hWnd := % hWnds%A_Index% ; get next hWnd
  WinClose, ahk_id %hWnd%
}
```

Also note that the [`WinClose` documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) calls using `WinClose`'s use of the `WM_CLOSE` message "somewhat forceful" and suggests the following `PostMessage` alternative, which mimics the user action of pressing <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> or using the Window menu's `Close` item:

```
; Get all hWnds (window IDs) created by chrome.exe processes.
WinGet hWnds, List, ahk_exe chrome.exe

; Loop over all hWnds and close them.
Loop, %hWnds%
{
  hWnd := % hWnds%A_Index% ; get next hWnd
  PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, ahk_id %hWnd%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for 'soft closing' specific processes:

```
CloseAllInstances( exename )
{
    WinGet LhWnd, List, % "ahk_exe " exename
    Loop, %LhWnd%
        PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, % "ahk_id " LhWnd%A_Index%
}
```

So you simply need to call the following line to close all chrome instances:

```
CloseAllInstances( "chrome.exe" )
```